# Name of an 80's cartoon character?

Tags: cartoon, story-identification

Does anyone remember the name of this kid from an old 80's cartoon (and the name of the cartoon)?

[image: kid in jumpsuit]

Comment: Where did you get the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like [Dylan Taylor](http://www.aiowiki.com/wiki/Dylan_Taylor) from Adventures in Odyssey.  Notice the similar facial features in this image:

[image]

Here you can see him in a red and while shirt, similar to your image:

[[image]

Comment: Looking for his name...

Comment: @TZHX Thanks! Edited answer and gave you credit.  My rushed Google Fu was failing me and I didn't have time to find it later in the evening.

Comment: @TZHX Thanks a lot!